# Why does the order of NgModule imports matter?

Tags: angular

I have been going through the Angular tutorial and when going through the HTTP section https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html and have noticed that the order in which imports are declared in the NgModule makes a difference in terms of whether or not the application works.  I would like to know why that is.

In particular this works:

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
        AppRoutingModule
      ],
    ... 
    })
```

but the following does not.  The list of heroes does not get loaded.  Note that the HttpModule is declared AFTER the InMemoryWebApiModule:

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
        HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule
      ],
     ...
    })
```

The tutorial is using Angular 2.4.4.  I have noticed the problem in both Firefox and IE.  I have not found anything in my google searches that would indicate the source of the problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The order of **providers** matters. For **exported** components, directives, or pipes it doesn't matter, because conflicts result in errors.

The `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),` overrides `Http`, and if `HttpModule` is provided later, this overriding is rendered void.
**Providers added later override already registered providers with the same key**.

Comment: Thanks this helps.  I found this in the readme of the InMemoryWebApi: "Always import the InMemoryWebApiModule after the HttpModule to ensure that the XHRBackend provider of the InMemoryWebApiModule supersedes all others."  This is basically what you said.

Comment: the imports order matters too, I noticed that if I put AppRoutingModule after a custom module, than it will load that custom module as first page instead the one defined in the AppRoutingModule

Comment: In a "normal" use case, does this only become an issue with `HttpModule` ? I recently was modifying some modules to tidy them up by arranging the order of imports alphabetically. I got used to having Angular modules like `CommonModule` and `BrowserModule` and `HttpModule` be on top but when I know that these modules are imported already on "higher" modules like in the root `AppModule`, I now just do my thing, arranging my on the little modules alphabetically and so far nothing broke. I'm not sure if it might be just luck and what I am thinking about the higher modules is completely wrong.

Comment: @ColdCerberus the order matters if more than one provider is registered for the same "key". If you have `providers: [ { provide: MyService, useClass: MyServiceImpl }, { provide: MyService, useClass: MyServiceImpl2 } ]` then only the later takes effect. If you import modules with providers, then this happens behind the scenes and harder to spot.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Order is important if one module depends on another.

Comment: why the order is important in this case?