# Problem with directives and Two-way Binding in angular 13.1

Tags: angular, angular-directive, 2-way-object-databinding

My problem is that even though I import the modules " FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule" to the app.module.ts file and I have verified that everything is well written, it still shows me the following errors:

> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

> 'Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly an all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".ng
>
> Property binding ngIfElse not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure
> that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".ng

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'p'.ng

> Can't bind to 'ngIfElse' since it isn't a known property of 'p'.ng','Property binding
> ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".ng

> Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.ng

despite the fact that the application is working correctly, but it bothers me that they mark that type of errors, does anyone have any information about it, if it is a visual studio code problem or am I omitting something? thanks,

[img of .html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTDdS.png)

[img of app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDWKm.png)

Answer (score 1):

you need to correct the order of imports array in `app.module.ts`

```
imports: [
CommonModule,
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
AppRoutingModule
]
```

see more details here: [Order of ngModule imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144970/why-does-the-order-of-ngmodule-imports-matter). You can also try `ng serve` running again.